# How do I check the kernel version of a specific Linux distro version (not installed)?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

For example, I would like to know the kernel version CentOS 7.4 1708 uses. What is the easiest way to do it?

Do I need to dig official website or there is a more easy way like a database or something around the internet?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the distribution comparison feature on DistroWatch.com](https://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?firstlist=centos&secondlist=fedora&firstversions=0&resource=compare-packages&secondversions=1) to see which version of the kernel is used: look for “linux” in the list of packages.

Note that kernels used in long-running distributions such as CentOS will show a fixed base version, but they include many patches backported from later versions.